# *ngif - check the if the dropdown directive value is equals to this string

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

I'm new to angular JS

Is there anyways to hide this component if the user selects "All Months" in the dropdown.
[image]

I'm trying to add @ngif to this component

```
<app-monthly-summary-metric-card
*ngIf="this.filters.month === 'All Months'"
class="p-3 ml-3"
[model]="metrics"></app-monthly-summary-metric-card>
```

is there anyways to make this possible?
Thank you

Comment: If dropdown returns selected value adequately then this looks fine, excepts  this `ngIf` has reverse condition, you are showing `app-monthly-summary-metric-card` if string is `All Months`, needs to be  `!==`

Comment: Thanks,@tony, but I've tried that way it still doesn't work.  im still trying to figure out whats the issue

Comment: Please post html of your dropdown

Comment: Are you sure `this.filters.month` is set to adequate value on dropdown change?

Comment: I think yes, it looks like this on my TS,  
  //New Added
  metrics: UIMonthlySummaryMetric = {
    month_text: '',
    month_index: 0,
    working_days: '',
    max_working_hours: '',
  };

  filters: {
    month: string;
    year: string;
    projects: UIProjecOption[];
  } = {
    month: '',
    year: '',
    projects: [],
  };